# joomla share variables between modules

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How I should set a variable in a module to be available in next (other) modules? for example:

**mod_hello:**

```
$name = 'David';
```

**mod_goodbye:**

```
echo 'Goodbye ' . $name; //Goodbye David
```

I'm using Joomla 2.5, And I can't use sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using `JFactory::getSession()` in Joomla.

**mod_hello:**

```
$name = 'David';
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', $name );
```

**mod_goodbye:**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$name    = $session->get('name');
echo 'Goodbye ' . $name; //Goodbye David
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible, and have never tried it, however if I'm wrong, someone please correct me.

What I would recommend doing is storing the value in a database table and you can get the value like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
->from('#__tablename');
$db->setQuery($query);
$name = $db->loadResult();

echo 'Goodbye ' . $name; //Goodbye David
```